# FileNotFoundException: Could not find file CleanArchitecture.WebApi.xml in .net6

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

when i run my dotnet project on macos i am getting this error.
i couldn't find solution [here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY0GY.png)
here is xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>CleanArchitecture.WebApi</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
    </members>
</doc>
```

if you need anything i can upload it

i try to run it on macos

Comment: I guess there is something with the Swagger file. Check the location, name or if it is in valid format.

Comment: Is your problem been solved ? Do you try `<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>` ?

Answer (score 0):

1- Right click on your `API` project and select properties. then you should check `Generate a file containing API documentation` item in the Build tab.

[image]

2 - In `AddSwaggerGen` method add the xml path:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
    {
         var filePath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory,
                                     "CleanArchitecture.WebApi.xml");
         c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath);
    });
}
```